# How to viewport scroll via draggable object

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable, viewport, smooth-scrolling

I am utilizing jQuery's draggable functionality.  The viewport div is the entire window size.  There is a draggable container div within the viewport which is much larger than the viewport itself giving the feel of looking through a window to see small portions of the container.  The container holds object divs which are also draggable.

Currently, I have the container div dragging properly and I have the object divs dragging around the viewport div properly as well.  The issue I am having is I want to "push" the viewport around if an object div comes within a particular pixel range of the edge of the viewport div.

JQuery's draggable function has a drag event which I have been trying to utilize on the objects.  I can get the viewport to scroll but, it requires the mouse keep the object moving at all times to keep the scroll going.  I am looking to have the object get within the pixel range and be able to not move the mouse but, still scroll.  I am at a loss at the moment as I cannot seem to find any solution that really fits my requirements.  Any help would be greatly appreciated and rewarded with my gratitude.

To see an example of what I am doing, please visit http://jsfiddle.net/trVZA/10/.  When the red box is dragged, the black object will drag around.  I have commented out my code on the drag event for the object as it will completely freeze the browser but, it is there for you to see my mistake.  When the object gets close to a wall I want the background water image to scroll around.